# How to represent days and time in Instructors_courses table

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

**Problem**

I need to make design database(ERD) for displaying schedule for every instructor

include

day of course(Saturday or Monday,etc)

And which time it will give course(period FROM 12 PM TO 03 PM ) .

And what course it will give(c# or SQL) .

**Example**

Instructor martin give course c# in Monday and Saturday for period 12 pm - 03 pm

And SQL in Sunday and Wednesday for period 12 pm - 03 pm .

**Details**

So that i designed the following tables :

Instructors table (InstractorID,InstractorName)

Courses table (CourseID,CourseName)

Instructors_courses table (instcourseID,InstractorID,CourseID)

And relation between instructors table and Courses table many to many so that
I do another table is Instructors_Courses table .

**My questions are**

1- How to represent days and time for every course added

Can i add table for time and table for days and make relation with

Instructors_courses table by adding day id and time id (one to many)

OR do it programming from user interface .

2- course start date and course end date these two fields how to represent in

table Instructors_courses table .

i can added but it will repeated with every course are this correct or what .

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have autoincrement or some coding pattern. For example MON8A10A means Monday 8-10AM. This is only going to work if you have only one classroom. If rooms also have codes you can add that too (MON8A10AR1). That way you can manage the courses, instructors and their time slots. You may add time start time, end time, day and classroom as columns as well.
2. Adding course start date and end date in course_instructor table is not wise since it is going to duplicate data. But your approach varies according to amount of data you have and the responsiveness of the system. If you have a lot of data and need to save storage better to have a separate table for that. But you need to create a relationship with that. Having multiple relationships can slow the retrieving results. But that is for very long relationships. If you only have 2 or 3 it will not a matter.